# How to save/read pdf generated by mPDF in Postgresql

Tags: php, postgresql

I've following PHP code to save generated pdf to postgresql as bytea:

```
session_start();

require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../../lib/mpdf/mpdf.php');
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../../class/Postgre.php');

ob_start();
include(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../FormVariables.php');
include(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../../assets/templates/form.php');
$html = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

$mpdf = new mPDF('utf-8', 'A4');
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);

$content = file_get_contents($mpdf->Output('','S'));

$postgre = new Postgre();
$postgre->connect();
$escaped = pg_escape_bytea($content);

$query = "
        INSERT INTO documents
        VALUES (
            '". $_SESSION['username'] ."',
            'form',
            1,
            '". $escaped."',
            '". $_SESSION['username'] ."_appraisal2015_1');";
$postgre->sendQuery($query);
$postgre->closeConnection();
```

and following PHP code to read pdf file from db:

```
include(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../../class/Postgre.php');

$postgre = new Postgre();
$postgre->connect();

$query = "SELECT file FROM documents WHERE type='form' AND owner_username='". $_POST['username'] ."';";
$postgre->sendQuery($query);
$fileBytea = pg_fetch_array($postgre->getQueryResult());
if($fileBytea){
    $file = $fileBytea['file'];
    header('Content-type: application/pdf');
    echo pg_unescape_bytea($file);
} else {
    $_SESSION['error']= "File does not exist.";
    header("Location: ../../../dashboard.php");
}

$postgre->closeConnection();
```

However when I wants to read this file from webpage I've got an error: "The result is not a valid file".

Could you help me to understand possible reasons why it's not working as supposed?

Comment: Did you set the bytea output format to "hex"? See: http://edgardksb.com/databases/postgresql/pg_unescape_bytea-doesnt-work-using-postgresql-9-0/, also comments at the bottom of https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-unescape-bytea.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was there:

```
$content = file_get_contents($mpdf->Output('','S'));

$postgre = new Postgre();
$postgre->connect();
$escaped = pg_escape_bytea($content);
```

I had to change:

```
$content = file_get_contents($mpdf->Output('','S'));
```

To this:

```
$content = $mpdf->Output('','S');
```